# Azure function v3 config file with DI getting nulls

Tags: dependency-injection, configuration, azure-functions, config, configuration-files

We have an Azure function v3 and we need to inject a service that requires an IConfiguration so our code is the following:

```
public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
{
    public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Services.AddSingleton<IService>((s) =>
        {
            var configuration = s.GetService<IConfiguration>();
            return new Service(configuration);
        });
    }
}
```

The local.settings.json:

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "myConfig1": "xx"
  }
}
```

The service is attempting to get the values but **gets nulls**:

```
    public Service(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        string myConfig1 = configuration["myConfig1"];
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved it with this:

```
public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
{
    public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Services.AddSingleton<IService>((s) =>
        {
            IConfiguration configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                    .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                    .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", true, true)
                    .Build();
            return new Service(configuration);
        });
    }
}
```